# Use array data in highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to display a chart with **highcharts**.
I have a **2-dimension-Array** with values for Inductance and Current.
How can I use that data to display a chart? I was looking for it, but I didn't find the correct answer... In the highcharts demos there are only cases wich you write directly the values, but never use an Array.
I'm using html+php+javascript in my web page.
If someone could help me, I would appreciate so much.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

P.S: If someone knows another way to display charts easier, I also would appreciate.

EDIT:

Thanks for answer.
I think that I don't understand so well this library... I will post my code

```
//I initialize the array with the name Array_L_I_XXXX with the results from my SQL query
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
    $Array_L_I_XXX[j][0] = $row4['L_value'];
    $Array_L_I_XXX[j][1] = $row4['I_value'];

        $j++;
    }     
 echo "<div style=\"margin: 0 1em\">";
 echo "<script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\"></script>";
 echo "<script src=\"http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js\"></script>";

 echo "<div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>";
```

Also, in the `<head>` part, I have the following code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
         },
            series: [{
            data: [<?php echo join($Array_L_I_XXX, ',') ?>],
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval
         }]
   });
</script>
```

That doens't work (for sure is so wrong...) but really I can't find the correct way to do this... Thanks!

---

- I have my 2D-array in php `Array_L_I[X][Y]`, and now, I insert the following code to call the highchart function:

  echo "";
      echo "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js\">";

  ```
  echo "<div id=\"container\" style=\"min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto\"></div>";
  ```

  - In the `<head>` section I have the code Highchart conde

My problem is that I don't know how to "send" this array to the highchart function to use my values (It is not like a js function that I can send some variables...)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Highcharts accepts data in the following formats: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data. These are of course javascript datatypes since Highcharts is a javascript product.  So, are you asking how to convert your 2d PHP array to a 2d javascript array?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow...
Please do not post your updates as answer instead Edit your existing question

Comment: ok, sorry I will edit

Answer (score 4):

Without much details, I'll assume you are returning a PHP array and need to convert it into a JS array for use in HighCharts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    js_array = new Array(<?php echo implode(',', $php_array); ?>);
</script>

HighCharts:

series: [{
        data: js_array
    }]
```

Follow this basic example and you can fine tune it for your project.

Comment: Don't know why the OP didn't give you a tick, but this answered my questions simply and clearly. Thanks Sri.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at article about combine php array and Highcharts.

http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database